# inverse of the sum of a diagonal and a symmetric matrix

Tags: inverse

I need to compute the inverse of the following sum of matrices:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & B \\ B^T & 0 \end{pmatrix} +D $$

where B is a non-negative matrix and D is a non-negative diagonal matrix. They are both real an square matrices.

Comment: Why do you think the inverse exists ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, non-negative matrices are those matrices with non-negative entries. Suppose, $\begin{pmatrix} 0&2\\2&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&B\\B^{T}&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix} 2&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$. Then the inverse of the sum of matrices doesn't exist.

Comment: you missed the point

Comment: Can you please explain the point? Because, I only followed the statement of your question.

Comment: I simply wanted to  ask if any of you is aware of a properties that allows me to easily compute IN GENERAL the inverse of the sum of two matrices, where one is diagonal D and the other one is a symmetric anti-diagonal matrix (as written above). I'm not interested in the specific cases where the inverse does not exist. But I guess I wrote the post in a sloppy way, and I am sorry for  that